# How to delay the appearance of sprites?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am almost done with the app I'm currently making but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out one feature I need for it. I have 5 different sprites that drop on the screen on random intervals and positions. My problem is I need to tell my code that for a certain amount of time, for example 20 seconds, only 1 of the sprites would appear at a time. Then after 20 seconds, more would start dropping at the same time. Here's how my method looks like for dropping the sprites:

```
//The init method
-(id) init
{
if((self=[super init])) {
    //Enable touch
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    //Allocate and initialise
    sprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];

    //Add the sprites
    [self schedule:@selector(scheduleDrop:)interval:2.0];
}
return self;
}

//Method to drop sprites
-(void)spriteDrop
{
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];

int RandomX = (arc4random() % 200);

NSString *strSprite = @"1.png";

switch(arc4random() % 5){
    case 1:
        strSprite = @"1.png";
        break;
    case 2:
        strSprite = @"2.png";
        break;
    case 3:
        strSprite = @"3.png";
        break;
    case 4:
        strSprite = @"4.png";
        break;
    case 5:
        strSprite = @"5.png";
        break;
}

sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:strSprite];
sprite.position = ccp(RandomX, 500);
sprite.scaleX = 40 / sprite.contentSize.width;
sprite.scaleY = 150 / winSize.height;

int posMinY = sprite.contentSize.width / 2;
int posMaxY = winSize.height - sprite.contentSize.height / 2;
int range = posMaxY - posMinY;
int actual = (arc4random()%range);
currentPos = actual;

[self addChild:baby];

int minDur = 2.0;
int maxDur = 5.0;
int rangeDur = maxDur - minDur;
int actualDur = (arc4random()%rangeDur) + minDur;

id drop = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDur position:ccp(actual, -sprite.contentSize.height/2)];
id dropDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteDropDone:)];
[sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:drop, dropDone, nil]];

sprite.tag = 1;
[sprites addObject: sprites];
}

//This is the method that schedules the drop
-(void)scheduleDrop:(ccTime)dt
{
[self spriteDrop];}
```

I hope there's somebody who would be able to help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want the number of sprites being dropped to change or the type (visually) to change over time.

One solution would be to have an ivar _numberOfSpritesToBeDropped. This could be increased in a method controlled by a scheduler at the requested time interval (e.g. 20 seconds). You'd then simply use this ivar in the method controlling the dispersing of the sprites...

If you simply want to add different kind of sprites every 20th. seconds you would simply change the random statement to

```
switch(arc4random() % _numberOfSpritesToBeDropped)...
```

Side note: your spriteDrop method seems to be doing more than simply dropping the sprites and it would certainly warrant to be split into two different methods.

Based on our discussion below, something like this perhaps:

```
NSInteger _maximumCurrentNumberOfSpritesAllowed;

-(id) init{
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) setup{
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
    sprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _maximumCurrentNumberOfSpritesAllowed = 1;
    [self schedule:@selector(scheduleDrop:)interval:2.0];
}


-(void)spriteDrop{
    if (sprites.count < _maximumCurrentNumberOfSpritesAllowed) {

        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];

        NSString *spriteName = [self randomSpriteName]; // I'd consider doing something similar with the position etc. as well
        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:spriteName];

        int RandomX = (arc4random() % 200);
        sprite.position = ccp(RandomX, 500);
        sprite.scaleX = 40 / sprite.contentSize.width;
        sprite.scaleY = 150 / winSize.height;

        int posMinY = sprite.contentSize.width / 2;
        int posMaxY = winSize.height - sprite.contentSize.height / 2;
        int range = posMaxY - posMinY;
        int actual = (arc4random()%range);
        currentPos = actual;

        [self addChild:baby];

        int minDur = 2.0;
        int maxDur = 5.0;
        int rangeDur = maxDur - minDur;
        int actualDur = (arc4random()%rangeDur) + minDur;

        id drop = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDur position:ccp(actual, -sprite.contentSize.height/2)];
        id dropDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteDropDone:)];
        [sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:drop, dropDone, nil]];

        sprite.tag = 1;
        [sprites addObject: sprites];
    }
}


-(NSString *)randomSpriteName{
    NSString *strSprite; 
    switch(arc4random() % 5){
        case 1:
            strSprite = @"1.png";
            break;
        case 2:
            strSprite = @"2.png";
            break;
        case 3:
            strSprite = @"3.png";
            break;
        case 4:
            strSprite = @"4.png";
            break;
        case 5:
            strSprite = @"5.png";
            break;
        default:
            strSprite = @"1.png";
            break;
    }

    return strSprite;
}


// Call this method with a scheduler at whatever interval you'd like
-(void) increaseMaximumNumberOfSpritesAllowed{
    _maximumCurrentNumberOfSpritesAllowed++;
}

//This is the method that schedules the drop
-(void)scheduleDrop:(ccTime)dt{
    [self spriteDrop];
}
```

Comment: It's the number of sprites dropping that I want to change. I'm still learning cocos2d and objective-c so I don't understand how to use the ivar. Can you please show an example or a link that has a good example using it?

Comment: An ivar is a class wide variable. Simply define an NSInteger in your implementation file before any method like so: NSInteger _nameOfIvar;

Comment: From what I can see, there's no numbering of sprites being sent at all. Your simply creating new ones every 2 seconds all the time. Oh, and what does the spriteDropDone method do?

Comment: The spriteDropDone method removes the sprite once it reaches a certain point in the y-axis of the screen.

Comment: OK, so at the moment you're calling the method displaying and moving the sprites every 2 seconds. The sprites take between 2-5 seconds to travel out of the screen(?) This would mean that sometimes you will have more than one sprite on the screen (if the former one hasn't left yet). Right? If the sprite is removed from the sprites array in the spriteDropDone method you could do a check to see if this array contains enough sprites already, before setting up a new one...

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot for explaining that. It helps a lot. I was beginning to get confused between the two intervals the longer I looked at both.

Comment: Although, if I were to change those intervals. For example the sprites would move every 10 seconds, then they leave the screen in 4-8 seconds, wouldn't that mean that only one sprite would appear at a time? What if like I stated in my original question, I wanted to show 2 or more sprites at the same time after a while?

Comment: That's what the increaseMaximumNumberOfSpritesAllowed method is for. As long as your sprites array is kept in check with whats actually visible you should be good to go.

Comment: I think you might have a small nightmare of a bug in your code as well: [sprites addObject: sprites]; should probably be [sprites addObject: sprite]; ? Also, what is "baby"? And finally the sprite you define in your method seems to be an ivar but could (and should) probably be defined locally as well.

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks a lot for all the help. I hope I could get it working now.

Comment: No sweat, if you have an improved version later I wouldn't mind having a look. Also, I wouldn't mind at all if you marked my reply as useful. ;)